# Calculating bulge factors for Polyline objects in BricsCAD

Tags: c#

According to the **DXF** instructions for the [BULGE](http://www.autodesk.com/techpubs/autocad/acad2000/dxf/vertex_dxf_06.htm) value (group code 42):

> Bulge (optional; default is 0). The bulge is the tangent of one fourth
> the included angle for an arc segment, made negative if the arc goes
> clockwise from the start point to the endpoint. A bulge of 0 indicates
> a straight segment, and a bulge of 1 is a semicircle.

Now, I found this [resource](http://www.lee-mac.com/bulgeconversion.html) about calculating bulges but it is for **lisp** programming. However, in part it also states:

> The curvature of a Polyline Arc segment is defined using a quantity
> known as bulge. This unit measures the deviation of the curve from the
> straight line (chord) joining the two vertices of the segment. It is
> defined as the ratio of the arc sagitta (versine) to half the length
> of the chord between the two vertices; this ratio is equal to the
> tangent of a quarter of the included arc angle between the two
> polyline vertices.
>
> In this way, a negative bulge indicates that the
> arc follows a clockwise direction from the first vertex to the next,
> with a positive bulge describing an anticlockwise oriented arc. A
> bulge of 0 indicates a straight segment, and a bulge of 1 is a
> semicircle.

I am writing a routine in C# for **BricsCAD** and trying to create a `Polyline` object with bulges. I am nearly there:

At the moment, this is how I construct the vertices. Please note that I am taking an extents and then offsetting the extents by a certain margin on either side. At the same time I am stitching in bulge values:

```
   Polyline oPolyRect = new Polyline();
    oPolyRect.AddVertexAt(0,
        new Point2d(extentsSelection3d.MinPoint.X - dMarginLeft, extentsSelection3d.MinPoint.Y), 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    oPolyRect.AddVertexAt(1,
        new Point2d(extentsSelection3d.MinPoint.X - dMarginLeft, extentsSelection3d.MaxPoint.Y), -0.5, 0.0, 0.0);
    oPolyRect.AddVertexAt(2,
        new Point2d(extentsSelection3d.MinPoint.X, extentsSelection3d.MaxPoint.Y + dMarginTop), 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    oPolyRect.AddVertexAt(3,
        new Point2d(extentsSelection3d.MaxPoint.X, extentsSelection3d.MaxPoint.Y + dMarginTop), -0.5, 0.0, 0.0);
    oPolyRect.AddVertexAt(4,
        new Point2d(extentsSelection3d.MaxPoint.X + dMarginRight, extentsSelection3d.MaxPoint.Y), 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    oPolyRect.AddVertexAt(5,
        new Point2d(extentsSelection3d.MaxPoint.X + dMarginRight, extentsSelection3d.MinPoint.Y), -0.5, 0.0, 0.0);
    oPolyRect.AddVertexAt(6,
        new Point2d(extentsSelection3d.MaxPoint.X, extentsSelection3d.MinPoint.Y - dMarginBottom), 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    oPolyRect.AddVertexAt(7,
        new Point2d(extentsSelection3d.MinPoint.X, extentsSelection3d.MinPoint.Y - dMarginBottom), -0.5, 0.0, 0.0);
    oPolyRect.AddVertexAt(8,
        new Point2d(extentsSelection3d.MinPoint.X - dMarginLeft, extentsSelection3d.MinPoint.Y), 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
```

In principle it is working. The problem is that bulge calculation. I picked -0.5 out of the air which is not good enough.

The `Polyline` object also exposes a `SetBulgeAt` method where you pass a vertex index and a bulge factor.

Can anyone please advise me on how to put what I have found into action so that I have the right bulge factors?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An excellent answer was kindly provided to me by BricsSys:

Look [here](http://www.acadnetwork.com/index.php?topic=250.0%20http://www.cadtutor.net/forum/showthread.php?43619-Calculate-the-bulge-of-an-arc).

I replicate just the C# code that works great:

```
public static class Extensions
{
        // Adds an arc (fillet) at each vertex, if able.
        public static void FilletAll(this Polyline pline, double radius)
    {
        int i = pline.Closed ? 0 : 1;
        for (int j = 0; j < pline.NumberOfVertices - i; j += 1 + pline.FilletAt(j, radius))
        { }
    }

    // Adds an arc (fillet) at the specified vertex. Returns 1 if the operation succeeded, 0 if it failed.
    public static int FilletAt(this Polyline pline, int index, double radius)
    {
        int prev = index == 0 && pline.Closed ? pline.NumberOfVertices - 1 : index - 1;

        if (pline.GetSegmentType(prev) != _AcDb.SegmentType.Line ||
          pline.GetSegmentType(index) != _AcDb.SegmentType.Line)
            return 0;

        LineSegment2d seg1 = pline.GetLineSegment2dAt(prev);
        LineSegment2d seg2 = pline.GetLineSegment2dAt(index);

        Vector2d vec1 = seg1.StartPoint - seg1.EndPoint;
        Vector2d vec2 = seg2.EndPoint - seg2.StartPoint;

        double angle = (Math.PI - vec1.GetAngleTo(vec2)) / 2.0;
        double dist = radius * Math.Tan(angle);
        if (dist > seg1.Length || dist > seg2.Length)
            return 0;

        Point2d pt1 = seg1.EndPoint + vec1.GetNormal() * dist;
        Point2d pt2 = seg2.StartPoint + vec2.GetNormal() * dist;

        double bulge = Math.Tan(angle / 2.0);
        if (Clockwise(seg1.StartPoint, seg1.EndPoint, seg2.EndPoint))
            bulge = -bulge;

        pline.AddVertexAt(index, pt1, bulge, 0.0, 0.0);
        pline.SetPointAt(index + 1, pt2);

        return 1;
    }

        // Evaluates if the points are clockwise.
        private static bool Clockwise(Point2d p1, Point2d p2, Point2d p3)
    {
        return ((p2.X - p1.X) * (p3.Y - p1.Y) - (p2.Y - p1.Y) * (p3.X - p1.X)) < 1e-8;
    }
}
```